# correct way to use auth.permission as a foreign key

Tags: django

```
class Designation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)


class Blog(model):
    name

class BlogContributors(model):
    user = model.ForeingKey(User)
    designation = models.ManyToManyField(Designation)
```

Each blog have there own designation

e.g.

blog 1 have writer, seo , billing manager

blog 2 have comment moderator, writer, e.t.c

permission on blog 1 writer may vary with blog 2 writer

and each user can have more than one designation for a blog.

What is the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I want to know what is the better way to achieve it and i have't tested this code, will it work ??